# AFDownloadRequestOperation crashes on 404 response

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I created a new project in xcode with only this code to test

```
NSString *cachePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    cachePath = [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"blabla.jpg"];

NSString *fileURL = @"http://en.wikipedia.org/dcjhbdkcjc";

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileURL]];
AFDownloadRequestOperation *operation = [[AFDownloadRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request targetPath:cachePath shouldResume:YES];

//AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}];
[operation start];
```

And crashes  when 404 is returned with the following error con console, none of the NSLog in the test code are ever called.

```
2014-08-22 16:51:33.809 AFDownloadTest[7106:3403] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[3]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101b39495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010172d99e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101b02dce -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 382
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101b2e23f +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 63
    4   AFDownloadTest                      0x000000010002a955 -[AFHTTPResponseSerializer validateResponse:data:error:] + 1893
    5   AFDownloadTest                      0x0000000100002cf2 -[AFDownloadRequestOperation connection:didReceiveData:] + 178
    6   Foundation                          0x000000010141e36b __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 48
    7   Foundation                          0x00000001012d1bdb -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 210
    8   Foundation                          0x00000001012d1aec -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 69
    9   Foundation                          0x00000001012d1e37 _NSURLConnectionDidReceiveData + 79
    10  CFNetwork                           0x0000000106ae8e05 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic23_delegate_cacheTrifectaEPK20_CFCachedURLResponseU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 778
    11  CFNetwork                           0x0000000106ae4802 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 84
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101adff74 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
    13  CFNetwork                           0x0000000106a573e7 _ZN19RunloopBlockContext7performEv + 133
    14  CFNetwork                           0x0000000106a57217 _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 247
    15  CFNetwork                           0x0000000106a5703a _ZN17MultiplexerSource8_performEPv + 72
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101ac8d21 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101ac85f2 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101ae446f __CFRunLoopRun + 767
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101ae3d83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    20  Foundation                          0x0000000101339fce -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 253
    21  Foundation                          0x00000001012dfdc0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 74
    22  AFDownloadTest                      0x0000000100011fe8 +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] + 280
    23  Foundation                          0x00000001013352df __NSThread__main__ + 1167
    24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010236e2fc _pthread_body + 131
    25  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010236e279 _pthread_body + 0
    26  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010236c4b1 thread_start + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Halting the app at the line 169 of the file AFURLConnectionOperation.m
which is  `[runLoop run];`

Comment: I don't know what URL you were trying to hit, and I assume you put a dummy one in your question,  but it couldn't be found (404 error).  That is the same result you get in a browser when looking for http://en.wikipedia.org/dcjhbdkcjc. If you use something like http://en.wikipiedia.org/Sears do you get the same error?

Comment: No, with any URL which responds with 20X I get no error, en.wikipiedia.org/Sears works fine, in the ideal case which I have never a bad URL it never crashes, but when getting a 404 response from any server,it crashes like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug on the AFDownloadRequestOperation code, was fixed on this commit a36bd98208, on sept 4, 2014